# Click the button if it is present, if not, continue updating the page

Tags: python, selenium

```
    driver.get(urlwoon)
    btn = driver.find_element_by_id('btn')
    while driver.find_element_by_id('btn')is None:
          driver.refresh()
    else:
          btn.click();
```

How to make the page refresh frequently and every time searches for the button ****Help me please*****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to click the button and if isn't found just driver refresh.

```
while True:
    try:
        btn = driver.find_element_by_id('btn')
        btn.click()
        break 
    except:
        driver.refresh()
```

If you want you could also use webdriver waits to allow for page loads as well.